# How to specify default sort in Spring Data @Repository find method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Is below the only way (not so "clean" IMHO)? I'd expect something like [`@SortDefault`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/SortDefault.SortDefaults.html) and `@PageableDefault`, but it's only for (REST) controllers and not applicable to Spring Data REST.

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM FacebookPost e WHERE e.commentsPaging.next IS NOT NULL ORDER BY e.creationTime ASC")
Page<FacebookPost> findByCommentsHasNext(Pageable pageable);
```

Additionally:

1. How to specify *multiple* columns for default sorting?
2. How to specify *calculated* column(s), i.e. involving `CASE WHEN` or functions (which can be indexed in PostgreSQL)?

Comment: Funny that I tried to google for this and I found my own question on stackoverflow. Hello my past :p

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if @SortDefault is what you're looking for but you can directly specify the type of ordering you'd like with the repository method name. For example, from reading your query, I'd name the method something as follows:

```
Page<FaceBookPost> findByCommentHasNextOrderByCreationTimeAsc(Pageable pageable);
```

If you dictate elsewhere that the field commentsPaging cannot be null, I don't think there would even be a need for a @Query above your method name since Spring will automatically go and perform the query for you.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that OrderBy can be used in method name. However, in my case I'm still looking for generic solution that can work with @Query